# What does 群峰争奇 mean here?

Tags: meaning

This little text is talking about types of clouds.

夏天，雷雨到来之前，在天空先会看到厚厚的积云。积云如果迅速地向上凸起，形成高大的云山，群峰争奇，耸入天顶，就变成了积雨云。

From zdic.net I see that 争 can mean： 4。 怎么，如何（多见于诗、词、曲）：～不。～知。～奈

形成高大的云山，群峰争奇，
1. form big high cloud mountains, (whose) peaks are very (争, 怎么， 这么） strange

or it means:

2. form big high cloud mountains, (whose) peaks compete (争） in strangeness (of form)

Or something else entirely?

Comment: exactly，cf。 bkrs：群峰 the peaks of a mountain range
a group of mountain peaks many mountain peaks
争奇 竞相逞其奇特, like many mountain peaks vying with each other in adopting/creating strange shapes

Comment: #2 - the peaks "compete for being more distinctive", implying they are all very distinctive already.

Comment: 形成 forming ....  strange mountain ranges vying with each other in originality

Answer (score 2):

積雲如果迅速地向上凸起，形成高大的雲山，群峰爭奇，聳入天頂，就變成了積雨雲。

If the cumulus bulged quickly forming huge mountain clouds, the peaks fight for their exquisiteness way up to the sky's zenith, they then become the Cumulonimbus.

Comment: 'exquisity'?? In which dictionary did you find that word? -:)

Comment: My fault, it should we exquisiteness, thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 0):

群means all , together
峰 means， peaks， here mountain peaks
争, means 争斗， compete， have a competition
奇， means 奇特， grotesquely amazing

So here is my translation.
形成高大的云山，群峰争奇，
 form big high cloud mountains whose peaks are taking an active part in the most grotesque-looking mountain peak competition. ( Everybody wants to be the winner.)

Hope you'll like my answer. Very anthropomorphic way to display the uniqueness and strangeness of clouds.